# Encode blob to mp3 with lamejs

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, navigator

I use a simple script to record audio from microphone, this code is simplified for presentation purposes.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new window.MediaRecorder(stream);

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
        const chunk = e.data;

        const fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            const mp3Data = [];
            const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128);
            const samples = new Int16Array(event.target.result);  // <- Some times this arrayBuffer contains Int16Array sometimes it doesn't

            var mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(samples);
            mp3Data.push(mp3Tmp);
            mp3Tmp = mp3encoder.flush();
            mp3Data.push(mp3Tmp);

            const blob = new Blob(mp3Data, {type: 'audio/mp3'});
            const file = new File([blob], 'audio-recording.mp3', {type: 'audio/mp3'});
        }
    }
});
```

What seems weird if the arrayBuffer contains Int16Array its length is small. So i'm kinda guessing that part is not working properly.

When i download the blob it's too short and only noise.

I've been trying to get this snippet to work whole day with no success.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Why are you doing this?  The MediaRecorder interface can already encode to a lossy codec like Opus, which has much higher quality than MP3, and even better licensing.

Comment: @Brad better browsers support

Comment: Why not use AAC then?